# Jquery switch issue

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I am passing a server-side variable `{{.PageType}}` which would contain one of two values, `newItem` or `exItem`. The server-side fills in the variable data, so when it reaches the browser `pageType` would be set to a hard value.

My issue is, if I pass `{{.PageType}} = "newItem"` everything listed in this switch statement gets disabled, though only the `#bCodeBtn` should be in that case. However, if I pass it `"exItem"` the `#bCodeBtn` does not get disabled, which is how it is supposed to work. So it seems that if `PageType=newItem` everything gets disabled, but if it's `exItem` the `bcodeBtn` remains active. Hope that makes sense.

```
var pageType="{{.PageType}}";
switch(pageType) {
    case "newItem":
        $('#bCodeBtn').addClass('clsDisableBtn');
        $('#bCodeBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
        //$('#bCodeBtn').blur();
    case "exItem":
        $('#selected_category').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#price').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#itemDescription').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#selectedColorCode').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Durp, figured it out after I asked. I forgot to include the break statement in each of the cases